# command values previously defined do not work?

Tags: python-3.x

I want to make a simple command using 'def'

```
     print("Hello World")
nb=input(("Insérer le nombre à multiplier : "))
max=input(("Combien de fois voulez vous multiplier ?: "))
print("Bien, maintenant utilisez la commande table")
def table(nb, max):
    i = 0
    while i < max:
        print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
        i += 1 # On incrémente i de 1 à chaque tour de boucle.
    else:
        print("Calcul Terminé ,-D")
```

So, the command table(8,9) for example works perfectly, but table doesn't work but what I don't understand is that the values nb and max have been defined before, so the command table should work even if values have not been defined in the command itself, instead it show me an error:

```
      table()
TypeError: table() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'nb' and 'max'
```

those arguments are by default the ones defined by the user at first sight, here it acts like variables nb and max has still no values, which is wrong since we defined them previously, how to make my method works or what is the shortest code that would work as the program intend to in my logic?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to define `nb` and `max` as global variables, then they will also be visible within your method `table()`.

```
global nb 
nb = int(input(("Insérer le nombre à multiplier : ")))
global max
max = int(input(("Combien de fois voulez vous multiplier ?: ")))
print("Bien, maintenant utilisez la commande table")
def table():
    i = 0
    while i < max:
        print(i + 1, "*", nb, "=", (i + 1) * nb)
        i += 1 # On incrémente i de 1 à chaque tour de boucle.
    else:
        print("Calcul Terminé ,-D")

table()
```

Note that I also added a type cast to `int` in your code, as arithmetic operations are not allowed on strings, and `input()` returns a value of type string.